# How to change MasterKey Expiration in Embedded XP SP3?

Tags: c#, c++, cryptography

Background: We have devices running embedded XP SP3, .NET Framework 3.5, with the windows partition (c:) write protected.  We are using System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData to encrypt and decrypt data (using DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine).

Issue: After approximately 3 months, we get intermittent "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state. " exceptions when we try to decrypt a value.  The encrypted value is stored in a file on a write-enabled drive and persists. After 1-3 power-cycles, the value does get decrypted.

From reading, it appears that the MasterKey may be expiring and renewing when we start up. However, the updated MasterKey may be lost due to our write protected drive when we power-cycle and the CryptographicException exception thrown.  I know LocalMachine scope is not as secure, however, the end user of this system does not have access to the XP SP3 embedded Operating System of the device and does not log in to the device.

Questions:

1. How can we update the MasterKey and change its expiration date programmatically?
2. Can the MasterKey be renewed prior to access, and if so, how?

Comment: *"If you use these methods during impersonation, you may receive the following error: "Key not valid for use in specified state." This occurs because the DPAPI stores the key data in user profiles. If the profile is not loaded, DPAPI won’t be able to perform the decryption."* Are you using user profile impersonation? I see the Cryptography API you are using, but can you link to some information about this "master key"?